Lax Pairs partial differential equations evans chapter 4 exercise 11
This is chapter 4 exercise 11 of evan's partial differential equations.
(Lax pairs) Assume that $\{L(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ is a family of symmetric linear operators on some real Hilbert space $H$, satisfying the evolution equation
$$
\dot{L}=[B, L]=B L-L B,
$$
for some collection of operators $\{B(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$. Suppose also that we have a corresponding family of eigenvalues $\{\lambda(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ and eigenvectors $\{w(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ :
$$
L(t) w(t)=\lambda(t) w(t) .
$$
Assume that $L, B, \lambda$ and $w$ all depend smoothly upon the time parameter $t$.
Show that
$$
\dot{\lambda} \equiv 0 .
$$
(Hint: Differentiate the identity $L w=\lambda w$ with respect to $t$. Calculate $(\dot{\lambda} w, w)$.
Based on the hint, after differentiating $L w=\lambda w$ we obtain
$$\dot{L}w + L\dot{w} = \dot{\lambda} w + \lambda \dot{w}$$
$$[B, L]w + L\dot{w} = \dot{\lambda} w + \lambda \dot{w}$$
Solving for $\dot{\lambda}w$ we obtain
$$\dot{\lambda}w =[B, L]w + L\dot{w} - \dot{\lambda} w $$
Taking the inner product with $w$ we obtain
$$(\dot{\lambda}w, w)=([B, L]w + L\dot{w} - \dot{\lambda} w, w) = ([B, L]w, w) + (L\dot{w}, w) - (\dot{\lambda} w, w)$$
I'm guessing we want to show that the RHS is $0$. But I'm struggling to see this cn be done especially when we don't know what $B$ is.

Notice that if $L$ has a Lax Pair $[B,L]$, we have
$$
\dot{L}w=[B,L]w=(BL-LB)w=BLw-LBw=\lambda Bw-LBw=(\lambda I-L)Bw
$$
since $Lw=\lambda w$. If we inner product this with $w$, we get
$$
(\dot{L}w,w)=\lambda(Bw,w)-(LBw,w)=\lambda(Bw,w)-(Bw,Lw)=\lambda(Bw,w)-(Bw,\lambda w)=0
$$
where we have used the symmetry of $L$, so we know that $(\dot{L}w,w)=0$. We differentiate the expression $Lw=\lambda w$ to get
$$
\dot{L}w+L\dot{w}=\dot{\lambda}w+\lambda\dot{w}
$$
Taking the inner product with $w$ and using out previous result,
$$
(L\dot{w},w)=\dot{\lambda}(w,w)+\lambda(\dot{w},w)
$$
By the symmetry of $L$, the left side reads
$$
(L\dot{w},w)=(\dot{w},Lw)=(\dot{w},\lambda w)=\lambda(\dot{w},w)
$$
We subtract this from both sides and get $\dot{\lambda}(w,w)=0$, and since $w$ must be a nonzero eigenvector we have $\dot{\lambda}=0$.

Is the reason you can factor out $\lambda$ out of the inner product because although it's not a constant (with respect to time), it's a constant with respect the space $H$?

The function $\lambda$ is a scalar function, not a vector function. As such, it is not even the case that each $\lambda(t)$ belongs to $H$, but instead belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ (or in the general case, $\mathbb{C}$). The inner product operations is linear with respect to scalars, and so both $\lambda$ and $\dot{\lambda}$ may be factored out of any inner product we have.
